# The twitter API seems to escape ampersand, <, > but nothing else?

Tags: twitter

I wrote the following test tweet:

```
&“”‘’®©™¶•·§–—
```

Then fetched it using the 'user_timeline' api call. The following json was returned:

```
...
"text": "&amp;“”‘’®©™¶•·§–—",
...
```

It seems strange the ampersand is the only escaped symbol.

Are there any other escaped symbols? I can't find a definitive list in the docs.

Alternatively, is it possible to specify if the api should return escaped/ unescaped characters?

Edit

Test tweet:

```
<>=+
```

Returns:

```
...
'text': '&lt;&gt;=+'
...
```

Comment: I am betting it escapes a straight double quote (not in your example -  you have smart quotes). In general it is unnecessary to escape an `&` in JSON.

Comment: Double quotes are not html escaped but slash escaped, eg \"

Comment: Indeed, that's what I'd expect. I doubt it's HTML escaping just to wrap it in JSON. What do `<`, `>`, `=`, `+`, and a space do?

Comment: <> are indeed html encoded. Updated the description. Space is unencoded

Comment: Also have noticed the same - I guess the solution is to just convert `&amp;` to `&` - seems weird that it is such a special case